# Reveiving a "undefined method `locale' for nil:NilClass" error when using I18n in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, internationalization, locale

I am trying to set the local of my users via a field in my user model called locale.
However, the I18n methods do not seem to be working. I'm not sure if I've missed some configuration or something. (I'm still new to rails.) I find that this also happens with many gems that I try to use. Possible that I am initializing things incorrectly?

```
undefined method default_locale for nil:NilClass
```

In my Application Controller:

```
 before_filter :set_locale 

 private 

 def set_locale # Sets the users language via the locale index. 
    I18n.default_local = 'en'
    I18n.locale = current_user.locale if current_user.locale.present? || I18n.default_locale
 end
```

Comment: In `set_locale` method i see `I18n.default_local = 'en'`. Did you mean `I18n.default_locale = 'en'`?

Comment: Your right, I missed typed it. I've got another error, but that might have been the problem. (I have very poor eyesight, -8.3!)

Comment: You should have got error on `I18n.default_local = 'en'` first stating `undefined method `default_local=' for I18n:Module`.

Comment: It seems that your `current_user` is nil. Check its value if it is set or not.

Comment: Ok, your correct. I think that since I am using a before filter on the application controller, that my method is being accessed before the user is logged in. (Via Devise)

Comment: Thus, current_user, would be nil. So I need to somehow check before hand if the current_user is nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that your `current_user` is nil. Just make sure that the `current_user` is set before you call `locale` on it.

Comment: def set_locale # Sets the users language via the locale index. 
    I18n.default_locale = 'en' # Set default to english.
    if current_user.nil?
      # User is not logged in.
    else
      I18n.locale = current_user.locale if current_user.locale.present? || I18n.default_locale
    end
  end